# How well does Webmin 1.580 work with 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, compatibility, webmin

we're using Ubuntu desktop 8.04 LTS as a server for our intranet and are currently planning an upgrade to 12.04 LTS.

However, since we're using Webmin, we're wondering whether Webmin 1.580 is a good fit for version 12.04, as there's a "development version" 1.587 out there to support 12.04.

Will 1.580 work with Ubuntu 12.04? Is the development version only there to add support to some new functionality from 12.04 or is it THE minimal version working on 12.04?

Anyone had it installed on production, yet?

Answer (score 1):

I'm running it on 11.10 without any problems. I can't imagine why running it on 12.04 would be a problem. You could setup a 12.04 box and test it before moving your production server.

Just out of curiosity, why are you running a server on a Desktop version?

Comment: An excellent question; I'm new here, but I think it's for the sake of the UI fall-back option.
As to whether it should work on 12.04, it's the mention "To support the new Ubuntu Linux 12.04 release, we have released Webmin development version 1.587 and Usermin 1.507 with full support for the new Ubuntu version." on webmin's site that is nagging me.

Answer (score 0):

You want the latest devel version, in this case. Ubuntu 12.04 has some changes in a few services that lead to issues, so all the devel releases in this cycle have been to address those changes that we found during the Virtualmin release testing for Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Thanks, but do you(or someone) know whether those issues are related to new 12.04 functionalities not being available with 1.580, or is it plainly unusable?

Comment: There are several Ubuntu 12.04 issues fixed by the 1.587 release...so, why not install the devel release, so you don't run into those issues?